# Select same columns from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with multiple tables and those tables contain multiple columns that are equal.

For example:

`table1` contains `productid`, `price`, and a couple of columns specific for that table.

`table2` contains `productid`, `price`, and a couple of different columns (not in `table1`)

`table3` also has `productid`, `price` and more unique columns, etc etc.

Is it possible to select `productid` and `price` from all three tables in one query and get the result in one output? One way would be to select into some temporary table, but is there an easier/better/nicer way?

Comment: yeas you can learn about join

Comment: do you need relevant data from all three tables which having same productid ?

Comment: @ krishn i've seen join only used to combine data 'horizontally', and not append data after other data. @ AMIT: I don't care if it's duplicated
The answer below (marked as correct) works for me!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

using the union :

```
    select productid,price from table1
union select productid,price from table2
union select productid,price from table3
```

Comment: This is just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

you can use aliases in your query, so you will be able to get different column, e.g:

```
select table1.productid as productId1, table1.price as price1, table2.prodcutid as productId2, ....
```

Answer (score 0):

useing below query you can get record from different table

```
SELECT t1.productid, t1.price,t2.productid, t2.price,t3.productid, t3.price from table1 t1,table2 t2 ,table3 t3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need relevant data among all tables which having common productid then you should use joins like:

```
select t1.productid as t1_productid,t1.price as t1_price,t1.othercol
t2.productid as t2_productid,t2.price as t2_price,t2.anothercol
t3.productid as t3_productid,t3.price as t3_price,t3.manymorecol from table1 t1 
inner join table2  t2 on t2.productid = t1.productid
inner join table3  t3 on t3.productid = t2.productid
```

let me know if you want another kind of output.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many tables have same strucure using the this code:

**Oracle**

```
Select ' Select productid,price'||
         ' from '|| table_name ||
         ' Union' quer
From tabs
Where table_name like 'table%';
```

**SQL Server**

```
Select ' Select productid,price'+
         ' from '+ table_name +
         ' Union' quer
From  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
where table_name  'table%';
```

after that copy the result and remove last union and execute it

Comment: Is there a way to do this with PLSQL and having table_name stored in a scalar variable?